# Javascript associative arry backwards by key value

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an associative array in javascript

```
parenthesis=[1: 25, 2: 11, 6: 10, 13: 24, 14: 21, 16: 20];
```

and I want to sort it backwards so like

```
parenthesis=[16:20, 14:21, 13:24, 6:10, 2:11, 1:25];
```

Whats the most efficient way to do this?

This is the full code. I want to reverse order of parenthesis as described^

```
function parseString(originalString){
originalString = originalString.replace(/ /g, '');
var openParenth = [];
var openPosition = -1;
var closeParenth = [];
var closePosition = -1;
var parenthesis = [];
var i;
var x=0;
var j;
while(originalString.indexOf("(",openPosition+1) != -1){
    openPosition = originalString.indexOf("(",openPosition+1);
    openParenth.push(openPosition);
}
while(originalString.indexOf(")", closePosition+1) != -1){
    closePosition = originalString.indexOf(")",closePosition+1);
    closeParenth.push(closePosition);
}
for(i=0; i<closeParenth.length; i++){
    while(openParenth[x] < closeParenth[i]){
        x++;
    }
    parenthesis[openParenth[x-1]] = closeParenth[i];
    openParenth.splice(x-1, 1);
    x = 0;
}
}
```

originalString = "2((2   +4(4+5)) + ((2(4+5))/3))";

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Something like this doesn't exist in JS. If you mean that you have an **object**, then there is no way to sort properties, they are always unsorted. If you need order, use an array.

Comment: @FelixKling, It seems they are parsing a string, so it's a custom format.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez -- That doesn't matter, JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays - there are objects - and objects are unsorted. OP probably wants an array of objects: `[{1:25}, ...]`